# How can I add specific data from one dataframe to another larger dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes; `df1` is for baseball games and `df2` is weather (rain) data  by stadiums.

```
df1
date         Stadium
2019-01-01   Yankee
2019-01-01   Dodger
2019-01-01   Coors
2019-01-02   Dodger
...
```

```
df2
date             Yankee     Dodger     Coors
2019-01-01       0          0.1        0.1
2019-01-02       0          0          0
2019-01-03       0          0.2        0.1
...
```

I would like to add a `df1$rain` column in `df1`, using appropriate data from `df2`. I have tried merging the two data frames, but it returns redundant and long data with too many columns.

Comment: Don't post picture of your dataframe. That's the main reason for these downvotes. Proper way would be using `dput`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just joined and didn't know how to format :(

Comment: no worries. I was just letting you know, so you can get better help from this community. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `match` from `base R` to get the `row/column` index, use that to extract the values from the second dataset to create the column 'rain' in first dataset

```
df1$rain <-  df2[-1][cbind(match(df1$date, df2$date), 
                           match(df1$Stadium, names(df2)[-1]))]
```

---

Or another option is to convert the second dataset into 'long' format and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = 'Stadium', values_to = 'rain') %>%
   right_join(df1)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  date       Stadium  rain
#  <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01 Yankee    0  
#2 2019-01-01 Dodger    0.1
#3 2019-01-01 Coors     0.1
#4 2019-01-02 Dodger    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", 
"2019-01-02"), Stadium = c("Yankee", "Dodger", "Coors", "Dodger"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"
), Yankee = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Dodger = c(0.1, 0, 0.2), Coors = c(0.1, 
0, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly. I am still trying to understand the cbind function and I didn't know that you could add match functions in it! Thanks.

Comment: @viatmincode  It is based row/column indexing to extract the element from the position index.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df2), id.vars = 'date', 
                 variable.name = "Stadium", 
                 value.name = "rain")[setDT(df1), on = .(date, Stadium)]
```

Another `tidyverse` solution, using `tidyr::gather`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
  gather(Stadium, rain, -date) %>% 
  right_join(df1)
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="
date         Stadium
2019-01-01   Yankee
2019-01-01   Dodger
2019-01-01   Coors
2019-01-02   Dodger", 
                  header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- read.table(text="
date             Yankee     Dodger     Coors
2019-01-01       0          0.1        0.1
2019-01-02       0          0          0
2019-01-03       0          0.2        0.1", 
                  header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```